# Meteor two apps one account system

Tags: meteor

I have two meteor apps

1. Main with accounts
2. 3rd party dashboard

What I want to do is to automatically propagate logged in user from main app to 3rd party app (SSO)

If (in one browser) user is already logged in in main app and starts other app i want userId in this external app

is it somehow possible already with DDP.connect() ?

Comment: Are these apps hosted on different domains?

Comment: in this particular example 3rd party app is hosted on a subdomain but in general it could be different one

Comment: if it's a subdomain anyway why not move it under the same domain and use e.g. iron-router such as `example.com` (that's main) and `exmaple.com/dashboard`?

Comment: Because I need functionality to allow users create their own apps on top of our DDP API with users synchronization. This functionality is already in development in SSO2 branch

Answer (score 0):

The best possible approach right now would be to use [meteor_loginwithexternalservice](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithexternalservice).

"These functions initiate the login process with an external service (eg: Facebook, Google, etc), using OAuth"

You could create your own OAuth for the Main app with accounts and it into the subdomain app using oAuth.